# Don't understand the output of the given code

Tags: c++

Just jumped into C++ and tried to run the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class BST_Node{
    private:
        int val;
        BST_Node* left;
        BST_Node* right;
    public:
        void setVal(int);
        int getVal();
        void setLeft(BST_Node*);
        BST_Node* getLeft();
        void setRight(BST_Node*);
        BST_Node* getRight();
        BST_Node(int val){this->val=val;this->left=nullptr;this->right=nullptr;}
};

class BST{
    private:
        BST_Node* root;
    public:
        void setBSTRoot(BST_Node* node){root=node;}
        BST_Node* getBSTRoot(){return this->root;}
};

BST createBST(int*, int);

void placeNode(BST_Node*, int);
void BST_Node::setVal(int val){
    this->val = val;
    cout<<"11: "<< val << endl;
}

int BST_Node::getVal(){
    return this->val;
}

void BST_Node::setLeft(BST_Node* left){
    this->left = left;
}

void BST_Node::setRight(BST_Node* right){
    this->right = right;
}

BST_Node* BST_Node::getLeft(){
    return this->left;
}

BST_Node* BST_Node::getRight(){
    return this->right;

}

void print_inorder(BST_Node root){
    cout<<"working"<<endl;
    if(root.getLeft()!=nullptr){
        print_inorder(*(root.getLeft()));
    }
    cout<<"*"<<root.getLeft()->getVal() <<"*" << endl;
    cout<<"*"<<root.getVal() <<"*" << endl;
    cout<<"*"<<root.getRight()->getVal() <<"*" << endl;
}


BST createBST(int* arr, int arr_size){
    BST obj_bst;
    BST_Node* root;
    cout<<"0 "<<endl;
    root = obj_bst.getBSTRoot();
    cout<<"1: "<< (*arr) << endl;
    //cout<<"create BST " << root->getVal() <<endl;
    root->setVal(*arr);
    cout<<"2 "<<endl;
    cout<<"create BST " << root->getVal() <<endl;
    for(int i=1;i<arr_size;i++){
        cout<<"create BST " << root->getVal() <<endl;
        int curr_val = *(arr+i);
        placeNode(root,curr_val);
    }
    cout<<"create BST " << root->getVal() <<endl;
    return obj_bst;
}

void placeNode(BST_Node* root, int curr_val){
    int root_val = root->getVal();
    if((curr_val>root_val) && (root->getRight()!=nullptr) ){
        placeNode(root->getRight(), curr_val);
    }else if((curr_val<=root_val) && (root->getLeft()!=nullptr)){
        placeNode(root->getLeft(), curr_val);
    }else if((curr_val>root_val) && (root->getRight()==nullptr)){


        BST_Node node(curr_val);
        root->setRight(&node);
    }else if((curr_val<=root_val) && (root->getLeft()==nullptr)){
        BST_Node node(curr_val);
        root->setLeft(&node);
    }else{
        cout<< "Placement denied" << endl;
    }

}

//void createBST(int* arr, int arr_size);
int main(){
    int arr[10] = {23,23,34,1,2,343,343,23,4343};
    cout<<"working"<<endl;
    BST obj_bst = createBST(arr, 10);//sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)
    cout<<"working"<<endl;
    BST_Node root = *(obj_bst.getBSTRoot());
    cout<<"working"<<endl;
    print_inorder(root);
    cout<<"working"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output I got is:
"
working
0 
1: 23
"
The execution stops after "root->setVal(*arr);" line in the "createBST" method. Any explanation would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Sorry about too much code. I did not know what else could have been done here to post the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "the execution stops"? Is there a segfault?

Comment: Have you stepped through it with a debugger? Try stepping through the `createBST` method one line at a time and you should find the source of the problem.

Comment: Why did you not look at the error that you got?

Comment: No error message mate..as @bjhend rightly mentioned, it was a runtime crush because of an invalid pointer. My compiler just showed "Program terminated with exit 0" :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not set a value to `BST::root` after creating `obj_bst`. Thus `obj_bst.getBSTRoot()` returns an invalid pointer on which you call `setVal` which causes a crash.